# XAMPP can't install because apple check it for malicious software?

Tags: database, xampp

After i'm gone download xampp, i got issue XAMPP cannot install in mac m1, in here i share pic below

[XAMPP issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoQks.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can grant an exception for a blocked app by clicking the Open Anyway button in the General pane of Security & Privacy preferences. This button is available for about an hour after you try to open the app.